# Need to make my spark code parallel processed

Tags: apache-spark

i have 2 dataframes. have one column in one dataframe having list of values in each cell. need to check if any one of these values is present in other dataframe.
i am currently doing collect on both the dataframes and treating both as list of rows to perform the operation. issue is now since a collect is done entire dataframe will be on the driver.can it be done through parallel processing ?

Comment: Please, read the following link about _How do I ask a good question?_: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be great if you could show us your dataframes

Comment: datarame 1:
id list version
101 3,5,6,7 1
102 12,14,15 3

Comment: dataframe 2: id individualfrmlist version
101 8 2

Comment: from dataframe 1 i have to check all the values from list and see if in dataframe 2 for the same id and version value plus one; whether individualfrm list is present.

Comment: long story short, dataframe contains older version data. and one id can value multiple value in list. dataframe 2 contains latest version data.if in new version these values are not there then it means it is deleted.

Comment: How about a response? Helped you at all?

Comment: no still waiting

Answer (score 0):

Save both DFs as SPARK SQL tempviews and write SQL against both with EXISTS. There are other ways, but this sounds like existency check via (nested) correlated subquery. SPARK 2.x. assumed.

Right from the databricks docs, an example:

```
%sql
SELECT  *
 FROM    employee A
WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  1
                      FROM    visit B
                     WHERE   B.employee_id = A.employee_id)
```

For the records as there seem to be a few such questions and SQL is becoming popular again: In SPARK SQL the EXISTS based subqueries are planned using LEFT SEMI joins for EXISTS and LEFT ANTI joins for NOT EXISTS.